# Is there a Ruby ORM that uses plain ruby objects and doesn't require you to inherit from a base class?

Tags: ruby, orm, domain-driven-design

I'm interested in writing a pure ruby domain model and adding persistence later on in development.

Some tools I've used with other langages like Microsoft's Entity Framework, now let you use plain objects for your domain data models, and then add them to a persistence class later through the use of convention based mapping. For example these plain objects:

[image: Plain C# classes]

Are added to a database context class here:

[image: Plain C# classes added to db class]

This can be very usefully not only for separating concerns during testing, but also allows for more manageable code, adherence to the SRP, and the ability to swap out your persistence layer easily should the need ever arise.

I can't find anything that quite fits the bill right now ORM-wise in the ruby sphere. ActiveRecord, DataMapper and Sequel all inherit from a base class tied to those frameworks. Are there any projects in progress, alternative methods or practices to achieve this?

Comment: For MongoDB there's Mongoid. It requires you to include a module instead of inheriting from a class :)

Comment: I don't know how this would work. Ruby doesn't have static types, so you need metaprogramming to declare the fields. This means you have to inherit from a base class or mixin a module. Also, why screenshots instead of code?

Comment: you can use FactoryGirl for testing. You then don't need to initialize the full objects, just stubs. Also, I think Avdi Grimm wrote a blog post on first working with plain objects. I know where you're getting at but don't remember exactly how you get there.

Comment: @NiklasB. Conceptually it did seem difficult, if not impossible, I didn't know if it has been tackled by cleverer people than myself though. As for the screenshots, for simplicities sake I borrowed them from Scott Gu's blog: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/ I've always wondered why he chooses to present code that way as well.

Comment: @Graham: No, I mean how would those stub classes look like? Ruby doesn't have static typing, so they would basically be empty (or you'd just use a hash). If you're concerned about putting logic into a model that you'd rather want to be independent of your persistence layer, why not put it in a module and mix it into your actual model class? You have to think differently in a dynamic language than in a strongly typed language (but you actually have more possibilities).

Comment: @NiklasB. I was thinking about mixing the plain ruby model object into a new class, e.g. User is mixed into PersistableUser which inherits from ActiveRecord. (Is there a better way to do this?) An ORM that supports POROs might help here because it could use the domain model relations (user has an array of orders = user has many orders) rather than having to redefine this relationship in the PersistableUser class.

Comment: The term "has an array of orders" has no inherent meaning in Ruby. To even declare this fact, you'd have to use some kind of metaprogramming layer. Note that with your mixin approach (which I think is a good idea), you don't have to repeat yourself: In your `User` module, you can just access `orders` without declaring it or knowing where it came from. You then actually define that attribute in the persistence layer. No repetition there.

Comment: Ruby Object Mapper (http://rom-rb.org) uses plain objects, but it's not ready for prime-time yet.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this one. It promotes a nice separation of concerns between your domain logic and persistence infrastructure layer. Obviously, it doesn't have all of the fancy ActiveRecord tools yet, but is a nice project and worth a look:

https://github.com/fredwu/datamappify

**UPDATE**

As we can see by this [discussion](https://github.com/fredwu/datamappify/issues/31), unfortunately the project is no longer maintained. :(